# Ruby on Rails ECommerce Platforms

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I've been browsing the web looking for an ecommerce platform to use in Ruby on Rails.  So far the most promising ones I've been able to find is Spree, Solidus and ROR Ecommerce.  The only problem I'm having is from the demos I'm seeing of them they don't allow you to add options to our products which is bad in my case because I want to be able to offer the customer sizes on shirts.  So far it looks like if I want to offer S, M, L, XL and 2XL sizes that I'm going to have to make 5 version of the same product.... which just won't work out.

Is there an ecommerce gem out there that allows you to have these options?  Or is there a way to modify one of these platforms to offer them?  I've been all over youtube looking at different tutorials on them and so far haven't come across anything that allows that.  Does anyone know of any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching an eCommerce framework for ROR. Most have some steps to use sample data. Just follow the steps in README.

Spree - https://github.com/spree/spree

Solidus - https://github.com/solidusio/solidus

ROR ecommerce doesn't seem to have much development going on, so I'm not focusing on it, but the README has a link to a demo, where you can simply log in and check it out.

I'm trying out Shoppe as well, which is also on Github tryshoppe/shoppe-example.

Comment: I created ror_ecommerce.  I can say the development is at a good place so there doesn't need to be much going on.  That said I do maintain and answer questions.  That said all three projects work the same.  You have one product with 3 variants (sizes in your case)

Comment: Just upgraded ror ecommerce to rails 5.  The ease of upgrading shows A) there is development going on B) it has great tests and hence can be upgraded easily